# Taylor expansion of time evolution operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, complex-numbers, time-evolution

Given the definition of an exponential of an operator
$$e^{\hat{O}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\hat{O}^{k}}{k!}$$
the expansion of the time evolution operator $\hat{U}=e^{-\frac{i\hat{H}t}{\hbar}}$ is $\hat{1}-\frac{i\hat{H}t}{\hbar}-\frac{\hat{H}^{2}t^{2}}{2\hbar^{2}}+\mbox{... }$ up to the second order. I have here
$$\left|\left<\phi\right|e^{-\frac{i\hat{H}t}{\hbar}}\left|{\phi}\right>\right|^{2}\simeq\left[\left<{\phi}\right|\left(\hat{1}+\frac{i\hat{H}t}{\hbar}-\frac{\hat{H}^{2}t^{2}}{2\hbar^{2}}\right)\left|{\phi}\right>\right]\cdot\left[\left<{\phi}\right|\left(\hat{1}-\frac{i\hat{H}t}{\hbar}-\frac{\hat{H}^{2}t^{2}}{2\hbar^{2}}\right)\left|{\phi}\right>\right]$$

Where did the plus in the first term come from?

Answer (score 3):

It comes from the complex conjugate:
$$\left|\left\langle\phi|e^{-\frac{i\hat{H}t}{\hbar}}|\phi\right\rangle\right|^2=\left\langle\phi|e^{-\frac{i\hat{H}t}{\hbar}}|\phi\right\rangle^*\left\langle\phi|e^{-\frac{i\hat{H}t}{\hbar}}|\phi\right\rangle=\left\langle\phi|e^{\frac{i\hat{H}t}{\hbar}}|\phi\right\rangle\left\langle\phi|e^{-\frac{i\hat{H}t}{\hbar}}|\phi\right\rangle$$

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the complex conjugation implicit in the absolute value squared,
$$\left|\langle\phi|A|\psi\rangle\right|^{2}=\left(\langle\phi|A|\psi\rangle\right)^{*}\langle\phi|A|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|A^{\dagger}|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|A|\psi\rangle.$$
This uses the relation $\langle\psi|\phi\rangle^{*}=\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ (for the [sesquilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) inner product), and the definition $\left(A|\phi\rangle\right)^{\dagger}=\left(A|\phi\rangle\right)^{*T}=\langle\phi|A^{\dagger}$ of the Hermitian conjugate of an operator.

In your expression, the bra and ket in the matrix element of the time evolution operator represent the same state, simplifying the expression to something of the form
$$\left|\langle\phi|A|\phi\rangle\right|^{2}=\langle\phi|A^{\dagger}|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|A|\phi\rangle.$$
Taking the Hermitian conjugate of $U$, the only thing that is affected by the conjugation is the factor of $i$ in the exponent; everything else is either pure numbers or Hermitian, $H^{\dagger}=H$.  So we have (using $i^{\dagger}=i^{*}=-i$)
$$U^{\dagger}=\left[\exp\left(\frac{-iHt}{\hbar}\right)\right]^{\dagger}=\left(I-\frac{iHt}{\hbar}-\frac{H^{2}t^{2}}{2\hbar^{2}}+\cdots\right)^{\dagger}\\=\left[I-\frac{(-i)Ht}{\hbar}-\frac{H^{2}t^{2}}{2\hbar^{2}}+\cdots\right]=\exp\left(\frac{iHt}{\hbar}\right).$$